# What does "stability" mean in regards to sum and scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to provide a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that is stable concerning scalar multiplication but not regarding summation, and the converse.

Question: What does "stability" in this context mean?

Comment: I think it means closed.  That is, $S$ is stable under scalar multiplication if $t x \in S$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ and $x \in S$.  It is stable under summation if $x+y \in S$ for all $x, y \in S$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hmm... do you have any tips for finding subset that is stable under multiplication but not addition? The task seems difficult.

Comment: Hint: think geometrically.  If $S$ is stable under scalar multiplication and $x \in S$, what else must be in $S$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok I got it thinking in terms of lines, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it means here that if $x \in D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ then 
for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^2$, ( and for $y \in D$ ) 
$$
\lambda x \in D \ \text{ and } \ x+y \notin D
$$

Comment: did you mean that lambda belongs in $\mathbb R$?